# Can a nonstatic member type be used without association with an instance of the enclosing class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Can a nonstatic member type be used without association with an instance of the enclosing class?

For example

```
class Outer {    
    class Inner {       

    }    
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner();    

    }    
}
```

In `Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner()`, does `Outer.Inner` use `Inner`without association to an instance of the enclosing class?

Is there other example where a nonstatic member type can be used without association with an instance of the enclosing class?

Thanks

Comment: the *type* does not care, but the variable `inner` "knows" `o`.

Comment: "Can a nonstatic member type be used without association with an instance of the enclosing class?" 
no

Comment: "Can be used without an enclosing instance" is exactly what `static` *means*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does `Outer.Inner` use `Inner` without association to an instance of the enclosing class?

In a sense, yes, because `Outer.Inner` refers to a *type*. And you never need instances in order to use *types*.

I think you mistakenly thought that `Outer.Inner` shouldn't work because there are an infinite number of different types called `Inner`, created with different instances of `Outer`. You might have thought that if I have two different instances of `Outer`, `o1` and `o2`, they will create different `Inner` *types*.

But this is entirely not true. You can totally do something like this:

```
Outer o1 = new Outer();
Outer o2 = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner1 = o1.new Inner();
Outer.Inner inner2 = o2.new Inner();
inner2 = inner1;
```

So `Outer.Inner` is just *one* type. It just so happens to be that an instance of this type requires an instance of `Outer` in order to be created.